# Visual Studio 2019 - C# - getting this error

Tags: c#

What to do to resolve this error of archiving my app please?

> Found conflicts between different versions of "Microsoft.CSharp" that could not be resolved.
>
> There was a conflict between "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
>
> "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was chosen because it was primary and "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" was not.
>
> References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll].
>
> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
>
> Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\Microsoft\Framework\MonoAndroid\v1.0\Microsoft.CSharp.dll".
>
> Microsoft.CSharp
> References which depend on "Microsoft.CSharp, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" [].
>
> C:\Users\MATRIX.nuget\packages\automapper\10.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\AutoMapper.dll
> Project file item includes which caused reference "C:\Users\MATRIX.nuget\packages\automapper\10.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\AutoMapper.dll".
> C:\Users\MATRIX.nuget\packages\automapper\10.1.1\lib\netstandard2.0\AutoMapper.dll WoWonder
>
> Warning CS0618 'JobIntentService' is obsolete: 'This class is obsoleted in this android platform' WoWonder C:\Users\MATRIX\Desktop\TimelineChat_V3.1.1\WoWonder\Activities\Chat\MsgTabbes\Services\ChatApiService.cs 25 Active
> Warning CS0618 'JobIntentService' is obsolete: 'This class is obsoleted in this android platform' WoWonder C:\Users\MATRIX\Desktop\TimelineChat_V3.1.1\WoWonder\Activities\NativePost\Services\PostApiService.cs 24 Active
> Warning ItemGroup `XamarinBuildDownloadRestoreAssemblyAar` is no longer supported. If your build is failing, revert to an older Xamarin.Build.Download version, or migrate your packages to use the new `XamarinBuildDownloadAndroidAarLibrary` ItemGroup. If your build is succeeding it is safe to ignore this warning. WoWonder
> Warning @(Content) build action is not supported WoWonder C:\Users\MATRIX\Desktop\TimelineChat_V3.1.1\WoWonder\environment.txt

Comment: Sounds like there are multiple versions of C# being referenced in csproj files that share a dependency.

Comment: Take a look in nuget package manager "consolidate" header

Answer (score 0):

fix it by updating Newtonsoft.Json package.
You can remove the reference to the old library and add the newer one.

Comment: Thank you, now the build started good. I will look forward to get an archive of my app and I will comment later here to see if i get successfully. Thank you SIR!

Comment: I get the built but next v.c.2019 gave this error in the final " XA5104: Could not locate the Android NDK. Please make sure the Android NDK is installed in the Android SDK Manager, or if using a custom NDK path, please ensure the $(AndroidNdkDirectory) MSBuild property is set to the custom path.
Done building project "WoWonder.csproj" -- FAILED.
Build FAILED. "

Comment: Any help please regarding to resolve this error?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/50FkaT1

Comment: The NDK is installed but the V.S 2019 seems to not get the path for some reason? Any command or documentation in order to make the software to know the path that needs to make my archive to be finish please? Thank you really much

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6001 I think this link can help you